# Wetty Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, npm

I'm trying to install wetty on Ubuntu 20.04, but I'm running into some issues. I get a lot of warnings and errors when I run the `npm install` command. All the guides I find are related to older version of Ubuntu. Is wetty supported for Ubuntu 20.04?

Here are the errors.

```
root@coral:~# node -v
v10.19.0
root@coral:~# npm -v
6.14.4
root@coral:~# git clone https://github.com/krishnasrinivas/wetty
Cloning into 'wetty'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2233, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (345/345), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (283/283), done.
remote: Total 2233 (delta 158), reused 160 (delta 56), pack-reused 1888
Receiving objects: 100% (2233/2233), 3.40 MiB | 6.31 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1163/1163), done.
root@coral:~# cd wetty
root@coral:~/wetty# npm install
npm WARN deprecated @types/winston@2.4.4: This is a stub types definition. winston provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated @types/socket.io-parser@3.0.0: This is a stub types definition.
socket.io-parser provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been
deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com>/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797) npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher. Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic. See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.3: "Please update to latest v2.3 or v2.2"
bufferutil@4.0.5 install /root/wetty/node_modules/bufferutil
node-gyp-build
sh: 1: node-gyp-build: Permission denied
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for open@8.4.0: wanted: {"node":">=12"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"}) npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: open@8.4.0
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules/rollup/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! bufferutil@4.0.5 install: node-gyp-build
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bufferutil@4.0.5 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2021-12-02T12_19_34_219Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I'm currently running WeTTY in a Docker container (to make things easy for myself), so you could consider this option. Although I haven't tested the latest version in Docker (no official image yet, but I'm looking into it).

Comment: Maybe you try `shellinabox` instead of `wetty`? It is in the Ubuntu repositiories, installs & runs without problems.